# How to select a colored item from a bulleted list

Tags: angular

Here is my menu

[image]

If I click on **Market** for example, the background color must be in green.

[image]

I don't understand why the **Currency** and the **Portfolio** are in green?

In fact, the green background appears depending on the menu selected.

How can I solve this problem, please?

I think that the problem is perhaps here

```
<li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === '{{ menu.route }}' }">
      <a routerLink="{{ menu.route }}"
        (click)="toggleMenu(i); selectedTab = '{{ menu.route }}'">
        <i class="{{ menu.class }}"></i>
        <span class="links_name"> {{ menu.item }} </span>
      </a>
</li>
```

**admin.component.html**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo-details">
    <i class="bx bxl-c-plus-plus"></i>
    <span class="logo_name">Menu</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links" *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index">
    <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === '{{ menu.route }}' }">
      <a
        routerLink="{{ menu.route }}"
        (click)="toggleMenu(i); selectedTab = '{{ menu.route }}'"
      >
        <i class="{{ menu.class }}"></i>
        <span class="links_name"> {{ menu.item }} </span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenus; let j = index">
      <li *ngIf="showSubmenu[i]">
        <a routerLink="{{ submenu.route }}">
          <i class="{{ submenu.class }}"></i>
          <span class="links_name"> {{ submenu.item }} </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="home-section">
  <nav>
    <div class="sidebar-button">
      <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
      <span class="dashboard">Dashboard</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

**TS**

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedTab!: string;

  showSubmenu: any[] = [];
  showInfo: any[] = [];

  menus: any[] = [
    /* Market */
    {
      class: 'bx bx-grid-alt',
      item: 'Market',
      route: 'market',

      submenus: [
        {
          class: 'bx bx-box',
          item: 'Item',
          route: 'item',
        },
      ],
    },

    /* Currency */

    {
      class: 'bx bx-grid-alt',
      item: 'Currency',
      route: 'currency',
    },

    /* Porfolio */

    {
      class: 'bx bx-box',
      item: 'Portfolio',
      route: 'portfolio',

      submenus: [
        {
          class: 'bx bx-grid-alt',
          item: 'Element',
          route: 'element',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I share you my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5e62ga?file=src/app/admin/admin.component.html).

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change like this:

```
<li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === menu.route }">
      <a
        [routerLink]="menu.route"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        (click)="toggleMenu(i); selectedTab = menu.route"
      >
        <i class="{{ menu.class }}"></i>
        <span class="links_name"> {{ menu.item }} </span>
      </a>
</li>
```

[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdjc7s?file=src/app/admin/admin.component.html) your stackblitz corrected.

Comment: another thing that you must to consider is when you want do binding don't add {{ and just use [routerLink]="menu.route"

Comment: Good point @MohammadrezaMohammadi, I will edit my answer with that to improve it.I upvote your comment as useful comment, thxs!

Comment: @Juan Vicente Berzosa Tejero: Thank you very much.